# How to Sum Dynamic Row Totals with One Excel Formula?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have 2 columns in my excel sheet: "hours" and "rate". I need to calculate Grand Total. The formula is simple: Hours * Rate = Total. Then SUM() all totals and you have a Grand Total. See screenshot below:

[image: Grand Total Calculation with Third Column]

However, **I was wondering if it's possible to calculate Grand Total without the use of "Total" column (column "C" in my example)?**
In other words: Formula = A2*B2 + A3*B3 + A4*B4 + .... but the formula should be dynamic, regardless of the number of rows.

Is it possible to do with Excel?
Thanks!

[image: Excel formula sum dynamic row totals]

Comment: In Excel you can use SUMPRODUCT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In B7:

```
=sumproduct(A2:A5,B2:B5)
```

does exactly what you describe in your question.

I don't know if Google Sheets has an equivalent.

Comment: According to [this](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294), yes, there is exactly the same one :)

Answer (score 1):

also possible in Google Sheets:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(A2:A5*B2:B5))
```

[image: 0]